# TestFlight downloaded app does not have location service enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, geolocation, testflight

I recently developed an app and download on my iPhone using development profile. It worked fine with location service via downloading through cable and from itunesconnect.

I submitted the same application for beta testing on itunesconnect and tried downloading via TestFlight. All works fine except that my app no longer uses location service. On iPhone settings, if I go and see then my app does not have possibility to use location services.

Yesterday I updated my iPhone with iOS 9.1, and it was iOS 6.x earlier. Does it have to do anything with the location service or TestFlight ?

Comment: Have you configured the plist correctly?

Comment: basically its the same plist. No changes in the app